# Typescript declarations for JavaScript SDK

Tags: interop, glue42

I am building my own application for interop using Glue42, does anyone have any TypeScript declarations that they could share?  I can't find anything in the docs.  This would really speed up my dev.

Searched on docs.glue42.com

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from the public NPM - [@glue42/desktop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@glue42/desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The npm package of the JavaScript library contains a TypeScript declarations file.

The file, named `tick42-glue-[versioning].tgz` is located under the `%localappdata%\Tick42\GlueSDK\GlueJS` folder.

You can install it with npm or unpack it with an archive tool and get the `.d.ts` file.